# javascript code to edit&save file on linux server?

Tags: php, javascript

is there any javascript code that I can use to **edit** (and maybe download and later upload the modified) text file on a linux server?

So I do not have to leave my web browser and do ssh all the time when I need to edit or even only check some config files? The server is not accessible from the Internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use AJAX to read the file, then use more AJAX to call a server-side script that writes to the file, preferably without introducing a security hole.

Comment: I was about some 'ready to go' solution for the editing part. When I AJAX the file to read then ... what? Do I have to change '\n' to <BR> etc etc.

Comment: @Radek: I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: If you want to build a remote text editor, you can use a `<textarea>`.

Answer (score 1):

file_get_contents() put in to textarea, edit, save with file_put_contents(), no js needed just a form and php. if you want fancy editing like for html then there's [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com) or [tinymce](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/).

Comment: do I need to take care of text, in terms of any kind of conversion? Unix <-> browser, text <-> html ?

Comment: perfect, then I try what `two of you` suggested ... I thought it would be more complicated ....

Comment: would any of the editors you mentioned support highlighting lines that contain provided string? Something like: highlight all lines with strings: `moodle` or `database`